# Spring webservices how to pass file bytes

Tags: web-services, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to write a spring webservices which will be used to pass a file as byte[] value. Is this possible using webservice? Can anybody show an example in any website? I have searched a lot and i could not find one. PLease help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

- [mtom](/questions/tagged/mtom) specification, supported e.g. in [jaxb](/questions/tagged/jaxb), looks like in [spring-ws](/questions/tagged/spring-ws) as well: [Stream MTOM Web Services in Spring Web Services Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842843)
- there are special data types in [xml-schema](/questions/tagged/xml-schema) to handle with binary data, see: [JAXB (un)marshalling of xsd types: xsd:base64Binary and xsd:hexBinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202108)
- finally you can serialize this data yourself to text format (e.g. using [base64](/questions/tagged/base64)) and pass as part of the request using simple `xsd:string` type